# Getting Rid of Annoying Buzzing Sound from Multimeter

Tags: multimeter

my multimeter has been bugging me with this buzzing sound that turns on and off while I'm using it. I think it has something to do with its autoranging feature, but I couldn't find the manual for this one and have a mind to get rid of the buzzing if it won't stop.

The model is a Craftsman 19736. I opened it up and discovered the culprit: a spinning thing with a blue and red wire going to it in the back case. Do you know what it's for and if it's OK to remove? 
[image]

[image]

Comment: How about just cutiing the red wire, oh no! Of course the blue wire!! All joking aside, just connect one of those wires and see what happens. It's a multimeter in batteries, not a chainsaw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Page 21 of the [user manual](https://c.shld.net/assets/own/03482334e.pdf) states:

> WRONG CONNECTION INDICATION
>
> The [buzzer] icon will appear in the upper right corner of the display
> and the buzzer will sound whenever the positive test lead is
> inserted into the 20A or uA/mA input jack and a non-current
> function is selected. If this occurs, turn the meter off and reinsert the test lead into the proper input jack for the function selected.

You can disconnect it or just avoid having the leads in the wrong socket.

Answer (score 1):

Pager or vibration motor. It spins with an offset weight to vibrate and buzz. It's for buzzing. Cut the wire and it won't buzz any more. Or replace it with an LED or something if you want.